# How can I grep a process in BusyBox using ps

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, busybox

I am getting below  error in jenkins pipeline when I try to run `ps -ef|grep process` command:

```
ps: unrecognized option: p
BusyBox v1.27.2 (2017-12-12 10:41:50 GMT) multi-call binary.
Usage: ps [-o COL1,COL2=HEADER]
Show list of processes
-o COL1,COL2=HEADER Select columns for displayI have Jenkins version 2.135 and
```

I have `BusyBox v1.27.2`

Can some one tell me how can I avoid this error for `ps -ef|grep process` without installing the `alpine image`

Comment: Can you share steps to reproduce? It works for me with `busybox:1.27`. Seems like some extra characters are getting passed as an argument to `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
docker exec -it container_name ps -ef | grep process
```

or you can do `ps -ef | grep process` into your container by running `docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash`